R.reclass is nowhere to find
I cannot find r.reclass in Processing - Toolbox.
I have GRASS plugin installed also. But it still does not work.

Which QGIS version are you working with ? Did you enable "GRASS GIS provider" via QGIS Plugins ?

I have r.reclass in QGIS 3.40.1 in Ubuntu (with GRASS 7) and Windows with (GRASS 8)
